# Mysql customer_details display other column value if address is missing

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query to display the customer id, customer name and contact details of customers and if address is missing then display the email id and if both address and email is missing then display ‘NA’ and i am sorting the results based on customer id but i am not getting any output.

My table structure

```
customer_id VARCHAR(10)
customer_name VARCHAR(20)
address VARCHAR(20)
phoneno BIGINT
email_id VARCHAR(20)
```

```
select customer_id,customer_name,phone_no,email_id from customers ,
where
if(address isnull) and if(email_id isnull) then 
"NA"
if(address isnull) then 
email_id
order by customer_id;
```

Firing the Query

```
Program Outpput
customer_id customer_name   phone_no    email_id    address
C001    Amith   9843123467  amith@gmail.com Bangalore
C002    Anand   9487256231  NULL    NA
C003    Bala    9442478962  bala@gmail.com  Chennai
C004    Gowri   9487267845  gowri@gmail.com Coimbatore
C005    Priya   9843134523  priya@gmail.com Cochin
C006    Prem    9528431343  prem@gmail.com  Coimbatore
C007    Rahul   9513428433  rahul@gmail.com rahul@gmail.com
C008    John    9982843342  john@gmail.com  Chennai
C009    Abdul   9843065418  abdul@gmail.com abdul@gmail.com

Expected Output
customer_id customer_name   contact_details
C001    Amith   Bangalore
C002    Anand   NA
C003    Bala    Chennai
C004    Gowri   Coimbatore
C005    Priya   Cochin
C006    Prem    Coimbatore
C007    Rahul   rahul@gmail.com
C008    John    Chennai
C009    Abdul   abdul@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name, COALESCE(address, email_id, 'NA')
AS contact_details
FROM customers;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a little more explanation than just the code to solve the problem at hand. This will help the asker not only to overcome the problem, but also understand why and how. Also, did you know that you can format your code by indenting it four spaces? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```sql
select customer_id,customer_name,
case
  when email_id is null and address is null then 'NA'
  when address is null then email_id
  else address
end as 'CONTACT_DETAILS'
FROM customers
order by customer_id;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id, customer_name, coalesce(address, email_id, 'NA') AS contact_details FROM customers ORDER BY customer_id ASC;
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id,customer_name,
case
when(phone_no is null and address is null) then
email_id 
when(phone_no is null) then 
address
else    
phone_no    
end contact_details from customer order by customer_id asc;
```